# Close virtual keyboard on button press

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

I have an `Activity` with an `EditText`, a button and a `ListView`.  The purpose is to type a search screen in the `EditText`, press the button and have the search results populate this list.

This is all working perfectly, but the virtual keyboard is behaving strange.

If I click the `EditText`, I get the virtual keyboard.  If I click the "Done" button on the virtual keyboard, it goes away.  However, if I click my search button before clicking "Done" on the virtual keyboard, the virtual keyboard stays and I can't get rid of it.  Clicking the "Done" button does not close the keyboard.  It changes the "Done" button from "Done" to an arrow and remains visible.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
mMyTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            // hide virtual keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_txtSearchText.getWindowToken(), 
                                      InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 312):

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                     InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

I put this right after the `onClick(View v)` event.

You need to import `android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager`;

The keyboard hides when you click the button.

Comment: Note: (in case you want to use this method in instances where there might not be focus (e.g. onPause(), etc):        `inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow((null == getCurrentFocus()) ? null : getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);`

Comment: You also have to import Context.

Comment: CAUTION: Throws NPE if keyboard is already hidden. Follow Peter's comment to avoid this.

Comment: why is the keyboard showing up after a click on an irrelevant button ? can someone provide some explanation or a link ?

Comment: Works like charm !

Answer (score 33):

**Use Below Code**

```
your_button_id.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try  {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Catching exception instead of simple null check, seriously?!

Comment: Working for me, hides keyboard on button click

Comment: simple solution to what I needed: hide keyboard after clicking search button.

Comment: worked without any issue.

Answer (score 13):

You should implement `OnEditorActionListener` for your EditView

```
public void performClickOnDone(EditView editView, final View button){
    textView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(EditView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            hideKeyboard();
            button.requestFocus();
            button.performClick();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And you hide keyboard by:

```
public void hideKeybord(View view) {
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                                  InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
}
```

You should also fire keyboard hiding in your button using `onClickListener`

Now clicking 'Done' on virtual keyboard and button will do the same - hide keyboard and perform click action.

Comment: Excellent, but I'm not quite following.  I think the post ate some of the code (there's nothing after "public void" in your sample).  I attempted to setOnEditorActionListner in my Activity's onCreate method, but it doesn't know what setOnEditorActionListener is.  I get an "Anonymous inner type" notification. (I'm doing this in my Activity onCreate method)  http://i37.tinypic.com/6ozkig.png

Comment: It looks like there are a couple of mistakes in this code, but it's the right idea. For one thing, the OnEditorActionListener interface is an inner class, so you need to either import it explicitly (Eclipse won't do it for you in this case) or refer to it as `TextView.OnEditorActionListener`.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble.  I've implemented onEditorActionListener (public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnEditorActionListener), I've attached a listener to my EditText (mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);), but Eclipse wont allow me to override the onEditorAction handler (public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)).  It says it must override a superclass method.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you can inline your OnEditorActionListener by typing   yourEditView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {....

Answer (score 12):

In your case, as you only have one EditText, the bellow solution is the best one, I believe. If you had more than one EditText component, then either you would need to focus on the EditText that you wanted to close, or call the bellow function for every EditText. For you though, this works brilliantly:

```
editText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Basically, the EditText already has a function that is intended to deal with what to do after the keyboard has been used. We just pass that we want to close the keyboard.

Comment: Can you leave an explanation of why your solution works so others can understand and learn from it? Thanks!

Comment: Sure Shawn. I just edited the top, since im new to posing if it is not clear just let me know and i will expand with the button onclick

Comment: Believe me this is one of most elegant of way of doing this. Thanks @Laert

Comment: This really is the better way to go!

Answer (score 12):

For Activity,

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

For Fragments, use **getActivity()**

*getActivity().getSystemService();*

*getActivity().getCurrentFocus();*

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 11):

Add the following code inside your button click event:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Works like charm!

Answer (score 7):

This solution works perfect for me:

```
private void showKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
}

private void closeKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

1. For Showing keyboard

   ```
   editText.requestFocus();
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
   ```
2. For Hide keyboard

   ```
   InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
   inputManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
   ```

Comment: "For Hide keyboard" method is a toogle (hide if is visible, show if is hidden) not a hide,

Answer (score 1):

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);enter code here}
```

Comment: Hi! Though this answer might suffice the needs of *@Andrew* it would be great, if you could extend it with some explaination, to make sure that future readers may benefit to the fullest of it!

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin example:

```
val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
```

from Fragment:

```
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity?.currentFocus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
```

from Activity:

```
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this code in your button click event

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crash Null Point Exception Fix:
I had a case where the keyboard might not open when the user clicks the button. You have to write an if statement to check that getCurrentFocus() isn't a null:

```
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you set `android:singleLine="true"`, automatically the button hides the keyboard¡